# How to throw Qualifier inside the class? Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a UseCase, which in the constructor accepts the implementation of the WallRepository interface. I have 2 implementations of this interface, which I have annotated with @NewsFeed and @UserProfile, respectively.

I want to be able to mark UseCase with these annotations in the ViewModel constructor of the class, and, depending on the annotation, create a UseCase with a specific implementation of the WallRepository interface. How to do it?

I tried marking UseCase in the ViewModel constructor with my qualifiers, but dagger still doesn't understand which WallRepository implementation needs to be created.